# How do I redirect a user to the same URL if the password/email validation fails?

Tags: php, validation, redirect

I have a password reset script that has email and password validation. How can I make the script redirect the user to the same URL (ie. "https://www.domain.com/resetpassword.php?token=...") if they fail to meet the validation? Currently, if the validation test fails, the user is redirected to the URL: https://www.domain.com/resetpassword.php. The token is now gone and the password reset page becomes useless.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  include 'connect.php';

// Was the form submitted?
if (isset($_POST['btn-reset']))
      {
// Gather the post data
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$email = strip_tags($email);

$pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
$pass = strip_tags($pass);

$cpass = trim($_POST['cpass']);
$cpass = strip_tags($cpass);


//basic email validation
if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
    $error = true;
    $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";

}

// password validation
if (empty($pass)){
    $error = true;
    $passError = "Please enter password.";
} else if(strlen($pass) < 6) {
    $error = true;
    $passError = "Password must have at least 6 characters.";
} else if($pass != $cpass) {
    $error = true;
    $passError = "Passwords do not match.";
}
// if there's no error, continue to process
if( !$error ) {

$token = $_POST ['token'];

// Retrieve token from database
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT token FROM token WHERE userEmail=? and NOW() < expire_date');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $resetKey = $row['token'];
}
// Does the new reset key match the old one?
if ($resetKey == $token && isset($token))
{
    if ($pass == $cpass)
    {
        //hash and secure the password
        $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        // Update the user's password
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE user SET userPass = ? WHERE userEmail = ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $password, $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $conn = null;
        $sucMSG = "Your password has been successfully reset.";
        unset($email);
        unset($pass);
        unset($cpass);
        unset($token);
        unset($resetKey);
    }
    else
        $matchError = "Your password's do not match.";
}
else
    $keyError = "Your password reset key is invalid.";
 }
}
?>
```

And then I have the errors appear in my form using PHP if the values of the errors are set.

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER)` and find what you need.

Comment: You should probably use ajax to post form.

Comment: @HSharma would using ajax to post the form eliminate this problem?

Comment: Yeah that's the reason people prefer AJAX in first place for such issues, if encountered.